# How to uniquely identify an AWS Lambda request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am working with AWS Lambda,
I want to know how I can uniquely identify a Lambda invocation request,
From the CloudWatch Logs I've figured out, there is a **requestId** associated with the CloudWatch Stream,

**It looks something like this -**
[image]

But also found that the event object of the lambda also contains a requestId under the requestcontext

So which one should be considered for Error logging?
The requestId from the Lambda handler's event object, or the cloudwatch one, or any?

Comment: The ID you get from the lambda handler's event object is the ID of AssumeRole Event. So, the requestID you will get in the CloudWatch log is used for the Error logging.

Comment: What language are you using for the Lambda function?

Comment: I’m using Node 8.10